# How do I create ID on a class HTML element on specific InnerHTML has no ID, with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, validation, addition, innerhtml

I have a problem with a code that can not run, I want a list that share the same class add a specific id for specific text.

I have this so far can not make it work.

**js**

```
function Check() {
    var x = new Array(); x[0] = "text to add id";
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("classtext").innerHTML == x[0]) {
        x.setAttribute("id", "first_id");} else{x.setAttribute("id", "Second_id");
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<blink>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="classtext">text normal second id</div>
            <div class="classtext">text to add id</div>
            <div class="classtext">text normal second id</div>
            <div class="classtext">text normal second id</div>
            <span onclick="Check()">Compare</span>
        </body>
    </html>
</blink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `document.getElementsByClassName("classtext")` will return an array of elements. So you can't access any property of them, you have to iterate over them first.

Next, your declaring an array `x` and trying to set an HTML attribute on that, I think that's a typo.

```
 var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("classtext");

 for ( var n = 0; n < elems.length; n++ )
 {
    if (elems[n].innerHTML == x[0]) {
          elems[n].setAttribute("id", "first_id");
    } 
    else {
          elems[n].setAttribute("id", "Second_id");
    }
 }
```

This might technicall work, ***BUT*** it will render elements with the same ID (`Second_id`). As per definition any id must be unique, which isn't the cas in this example. This will result in arbitrary results later ...

Answer (score 1):

try to use jquery for this. it will work as you need.

```
$(".classtext").each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == 'text to add id')
    {
       $(this).attr("id", "first_id");
    }
});
```

Comment: the idea is use only javascript jointly with ABP or stylish, to move, hide, etc. specific elements.